# Excel counting the number of entries filtered over categories, excluding duplicates

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I'm counting the attendance to the series of events. Each event participants' data is stored in different sheet, with the identical form:

| Name | Surname | Institution | Institution type - *dropdown list* |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Tom | Scott | tomscott | NGO |
| Hank | Green | vlogbrothers | Enterprise |
| CGP | Grey | cortex | NGO |
| Brady | Haran | periodicVideos | Local authority |
| John | Green | vlogbrothers | Enterprise |
| Derek | Muller | Veristiblium | Enterprise |
| Joe | Rogan | / | Citizen |
| Mr | Beast | / | Citizen |
| PewDie | Pie | / | Citizen |

The main sheet counts the attendance for the events in different columns (for simplicity, lets focus on the single example from above).

I would like to count the attendants from across different categories (Institution types), but count the individual institution only once.

Additionally, for the "Citizen" category, I would like to count each unique entry.

So, for the example above, we should have:

```
NGO: 2
Enterprise: 2
Local authority: 1
Citizens: 3
```

Right now, I am using something like this :

```
=@IF(UNIQUE(FILTER(A2:D10;D2:D10="NGO";"");;FALSE)=""; 0;INDEX(ROWS(UNIQUE(FILTER(A2:D10;D2:D10="NGO";"");;FALSE));1;1))
```

The second section of the formula is the main one. `FILTER` removes all rows that have different Institution type. `UNIQUE` finds if the entire row is unique not not repeating, `ROWS` then counts the number of entries, and `INDEX` reduces the resulting `a x b` cells into a single cell.
The `IF` check and the entire first (repeated) part accounts for the case if no entry with the required institution type exists, then the result is 0.

The issue is that this formula does not correctly count the number of institutions. For example, if there are multiple participants from vlogbrothers, they are counted separately, as their names are different. I would like to count the vlogbothers institution only once (resulting in only 2 Enterprises in this example), but retain the counting of individual people when in Citizen category.

Comment: Why can't you just add a simple `IF` clause to determine the columns over which `UNIQUE` should operate? For example, assuming cell `F1` contains your choice of *Institution Type*: `=ROWS(UNIQUE(FILTER(IF(F1="Citizen",A2:D10,C2:C10),D2:D10=F1)))`

Comment: This looks like an elegant solution. The only drawback is that it returns #CALC error if no entries for an _Institution type_ category exists.

For some reason, I did not think that an `IF` could result in different ranges of cells.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an improved formula giving you the right results:
`=IF(F2="Citizen", COUNTA(FILTER(Table1[Institution],Table1[Institution type]=F2)), COUNTA(UNIQUE(FILTER(Table1[Institution],Table1[Institution type]=F2))))`

- `COUNTA(FILTER(Table1[Institution],Table1[Institution type]=F2))` works for citizens, counting all rows
- `COUNTA(UNIQUE(FILTER(Table1[Institution],Table1[Institution type]=F2))))` works for non-citizens, counting unique institution names.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Please check whether following formulas are helpful to you.

NGO:
`=SUMPRODUCT(($D$2:$D$10=F2)*(MATCH($C$2:$C$10,$C$2:$C$10,)=ROW(1:9)))`

[image]

Enterprise:
`=SUMPRODUCT(($D$2:$D$10=F3)*(MATCH($C$2:$C$10,$C$2:$C$10,)=ROW(1:9)))`

Local authority:
`=SUMPRODUCT(($D$2:$D$10=F4)*(MATCH($C$2:$C$10,$C$2:$C$10,)=ROW(1:9)))`

Citizen:
`=COUNTIF($D$2:$D$10,F5)`

[image]

If there are duplicated citizens, it is recommended to use the following formula. `=SUMPRODUCT(($D$2:$D$14=F5)/COUNTIFS(A2:A14,A2:A14,B2:B14,B2:B14))`

[image]

Pleae note，the first three formulas for institutions are array formulas, we need to press Ctrl+Shift+Enter.

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit on the formula, and the idea behind it? Mainly the `MATCH` part.

I get that `($D$2:$D$10=F2)` checks if the cell is equal to the required _Institution_. 

`MATCH($C$2:$C$10;$C$2:$C$10;)`, where _lookup value_ and _lookup array_ are the same, returns the "largest value that is less than or equal to lookup value". 

The multiplication filters out the cells that are not correct institution.

After that, comparison with the row number provides the number of cells with appropriate institution, which are then summed.

Could the `SUM` work instead of `SUMPRODUCT`?

Comment: Additionally, I think that the _Citizen_ formula would incorrectly count the repeating people, for example if Joe Rogan is named twice, I would like him to be counted only once.

Comment: @teaboar  `MATCH($C$2:$C$10,$C$2:$C$10,)` formula will get the position number for institution in that Institution column, the duplicates will show their first occurrence of the sequence number. The result of `ROW(1:9)` is incremented and not repeated. `(MATCH($C$2:$C$10,$C$2:$C$10,)=ROW(1:9))` In the Sumproduct function can filter out the unique institutions. [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GTIiE.jpg)

Comment: @teaboar Under this array formula, the SUM function also works.

Comment: Although your answer is correct, Excel 365 has nice functions for this task which are much easier to use and read than SUMPRODUCT and MATCH.

Comment: ＠Máté Juhász　Thanks for your sharing.

Comment: Thank you @Emily, everything is clear now.

Comment: @MátéJuhász, perhaps could you share the functions you are referring to?

Comment: @teaboar those functions are included in my answer

Comment: Ah, sorry, did not check the username. Thank you!